# document.onkeydown conflicts on two different canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, keyboard-events

I am trying to setup two different canvas containing their own entity, movable with different keyboard inputs. Each canvas has its own script file.
However only the second canvas seems active, by testing I have come to the conclusion that the document.onkeydown() function of the second canvas makes my first canvas "non-active" (draw function is fine, but document.onkeydown and onkeyup not working), but I cannot find why.

Here is the code for the first canvas :

```
var canvas;
var player_y = 480/2;
const paddle_height = 100;
const paddle_width = 20;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
draw();
});

function draw() {

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//canvas
context.fillStyle = color[3];
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// Draw middle line
context.strokeStyle = color[1];
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, 0);
context.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height);
context.stroke();

//draw left paddle
context.fillStyle = color[1];
context.beginPath();
context.fillRect(10, player_y-paddle_height/2, paddle_width, paddle_height);
context.fill();
}

var UP = false; 
var DOWN = false;

function move() {
if(UP && player_y > paddle_height/2 ) { 
    player_y -= 5;
}
if(DOWN && player_y < 480 - paddle_height/2) {
    player_y += 5;  
}   
draw(); 
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 38) UP = true;
if(e.keyCode == 40) DOWN = true;
}

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 38) UP = false;
if (e.keyCode == 40) DOWN = false;
}

setInterval (update, 10);
function update() {
move();
}
```

And here is the code of the second canvas:

```
var canvas_exemple;
var cube = {
sz: 50,
x: 400/2,
y: 200/2,
sp: 5
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
canvas_exemple = document.getElementById('canvas_exemple');
draw_exemple();
});


function draw_exemple() {

var context = canvas_exemple.getContext('2d');

//canvas
context.fillStyle = "#242423";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas_exemple.width, canvas_exemple.height);


//draw cube
context.fillStyle = "#c70e0e";
context.beginPath();
context.fillRect(cube.x, cube.y, cube.sz, cube.sz);
context.fill();
}

function move_exemple() {
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 90 && cube.y > 0) cube.y -= cube.sp;
    if (e.keyCode == 83 && cube.y < 200 - cube.sz) cube.y += cube.sp;
    if (e.keyCode == 81 && cube.x > 0) cube.x -= cube.sp;
    if (e.keyCode == 68 && cube.x < 400 - cube.sz) cube.x += cube.sp;
    draw_exemple();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...but I cannot find why

Because you overwrite it:

```
// First file:
document.onkeydown = function (e) { /*...*/ };
// Second file:
document.onkeydown = function (e) { /*...*/ }; // <=== Overwrites the first
```

That's an assignment to a property. A property can have only one value (though there are some weird properties in the DOM, like `document.cookie`).

If you want to have multiple keydown handlers on `document`, use `addEventListener`, not assignment, but you probably don't want that. If you put two event handlers for `keydown` on the same document, **both** will get called. How do you determine which should do something?

Instead, put the handler on the `canvas` element, not `document`. That does mean that the user will have to focus the canvas in order for the keyboard events to go to it, but you have two canvases, so you needed some way for the user to indicate which one they were directing input to. (Note that to make it easier to focus the `canvas` element, you might want to put `tabindex="0"` on it [[details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)].)

(You could still use the handler on `document` if you wanted, but looking to see whether the event travelled through the relevant `canvas`, but in this case it's simpler just to add the handler to the `canvas`.)

I've included an example below. In the example, there's a lot of repeated code which normally I'd make a function I could pass things into, but I've kept it separate because the code is separate in your question and sometimes repeated code is simpler to read than parameterized code. You can use the mouse or tab to switch between the canvases. The active canvas has a green border around it.

```js
// Canvas 1
const canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
const ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
let x1 = Math.floor(canvas1.width / 2);
let y1 = Math.floor(canvas1.height / 2);
draw1();
canvas1.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    switch (event.key) {
        case "ArrowLeft":
            x1 = x1 > 0 ? x1 - 1 : x1;
            break;
        case "ArrowRight":
            x1 = x1 < 300 ? x1 + 1 : x1;
            break;
        case "ArrowUp":
            y1 = y1 > 0 ? y1 - 1 : y1;
            break;
        case "ArrowDown":
            y1 = y1 < 300 ? y1 + 1 : y1;
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    draw1();
});
function draw1() {
    ctx1.fillRect(x1, y1, 1, 1);
}

// Canvas 2
const canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
const ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
let x2 = Math.floor(canvas2.width / 2);
let y2 = Math.floor(canvas2.height / 2);
ctx2.fillRect(x2, y2, 1, 1);
canvas2.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    let originalX = x2;
    let originalY = y2;
    switch (event.key) {
        case "ArrowLeft":
            x2 = x2 > 0 ? x2 - 5 : x2;
            break;
        case "ArrowRight":
            x2 = x2 < 300 ? x2 + 5 : x2;
            break;
        case "ArrowUp":
            y2 = y2 > 0 ? y2 - 5 : y2;
            break;
        case "ArrowDown":
            y2 = y2 < 300 ? y2 + 5 : y2;
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    if (x2 !== originalX || y2 !== originalY) {
        ctx2.strokeStyle = "blue";
        ctx2.beginPath();
        ctx2.moveTo(originalX, originalY);
        ctx2.lineTo(x2, y2);
        ctx2.closePath();
        ctx2.stroke();
    }
});

// Focus the first canvas by default
canvas1.focus();
```

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
canvas {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 8px;
}
canvas:focus {
    outline: green solid 3px;
}
```

```html
<div>Canvas 1:</div>
<canvas id="canvas1" tabindex="0" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<div>Canvas 2:</div>
<canvas id="canvas2" tabindex="0" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: There should probably be a notice as to how to enable the canvas to be focusable (set its `tabindex` attribute to a numeric value, not too hard, but not obvious either). Also, they could have an other logic in place, like checking which canvas is in the screen when the event fires.

Comment: @Kaiido - Good point about `tabindex`. I assumed the two canvases were both on the screen at the same time, but that *is* an assumption...

Comment: I changed the code and used event listener on the second canvas conbined with tabindex, and it worked !

However putting the handler on the canvas element didn't seem to work, either with or without tabindex, as the event wasn't able to find the target id for some reason. But honestly as i started javascript a week ago, it might just be me being too noob to code it correctly.

Anyway, I have learned a lot, thanks for your answers !

Comment: @Gwaka - Glad that helped. I've added an example. Happy coding!